# Как в OpenGL получить цвет пикселей в текстуре, которая хранится в GLuint?

Tags: c++, opengl

Мне это нужно, чтобы получить средний цвет текстуры и добавить этот цвет как метку на мини-карту. Вроде SOIL хранит всю информацию в переменной, но как ее извлечь не знаю. По идее там должен извлекаться массив со цветом пикселей.

Загружаю текстуру так:

```
GLuint texture = SOIL_load_OGL_texture("путь",
        SOIL_LOAD_RGBA,
        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y
    );
```

Вот метод отрисовки:

```
void draw_sprite(int x, int y, double w, double h, GLuint texture, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    int compressed_size = 0;
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glColor4f(r, g, b, a);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(x, y, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(x, y + h, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(x + w, y + h, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(x + w, y, 0);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: Отмечу, что АПИ `glBegin` `glEnd` устарело и использовать его не следует.

Comment: @VTT Знаю, сейчас переходим как раз на другую версию, но здесь лучше сильно что-то не менять)

Answer (score 0):

Варианты по предпочтительности:

А. Посчитайте средний цвет один раз для всех текстур и храните/используйте его (наверняка вы захотите его модифицировать потом, сделать поярче или т.п.).

Б. Считайте средний цвет перед загрузкой текстуры в OpenGL сами.

В. Если используете mip-maps, то поищите как получить пиксели последнего уровня, он как раз 1х1 пиксель.

Comment: Вопрос как раз в том, как это сделать. Я думал, что можно через SOIL как-то, но там только карта высот. Возможно я что-то недопонимаю.

Comment: По идее мне нужно во время загрузки всех текстур в своём сдк, присвоить им цвета, в зависимости к примеру от цвета Mipmap 1x1. А потом с помощью libpng сохранить карту где эти текстуры отмечены их цветами. Проблема только в том, что я не знаю как получить цвет текстуры, даже если использовать ее размер 1x1